# Debian Install: The exchange of keys and association with the access point failed

Tags: key, wpa

I'm trying to do a Debian network install, the on board ethernet is dead so I installed 802.11 USB dongle. During the process the installer asks me for its firmware (mt7601u.bin) which is on firmware-misc-nonfree package. I downloaded the .deb, extracted the file to a 2nd USB memory, this way it seems the adapter is recognized properly.

However I'm still unable to connect to the access point, first I'm never offered to select a SSID, the installer directly asks me to enter it manually even when it's being broadcasted, I do it, then I choose WPA/WPA2 PSK which match the security in the AP, after a minute I get the error in the title. I have tried the 3 different WPA Algorithms.

AP is a WRT54G with DD-WRT v3.0-r40559 micro firmware.

Comment: Try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656993/debian-installer-failure-of-key-exchange-and-association-when-attempting-wifi).
Basically you have to enter ESSID manually

Comment: Try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656993/debian-installer-failure-of-key-exchange-and-association-when-attempting-wifi).
Basically you have to enter ESSID manually